# Regex : checking if string has 1 to 6 digits, and exactly 4 special characters

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to validate a string using a regex, the string must have 1 to 6 digits, and exactly 4 special characters (What I mean by special characters, are characters like $!^)("'. Non english/Latin characters can be interpreted as alphanumeric and do not really matter for this case.

I'm using this regex in a pattern attribute in an HTML input.

Example: 12?74@"=5  should be a valid string.

I have already tried :

```
([1-9]{1,6})([@"?']{4})
```

But it doesn't work like intended, I can't validate the string when the characters are mixed, example : 1254@@@@ is okai, but 12@@'?44 is not valid.

Can someone help me solve this problem ? I am new to regex and I need some help. Thanks !

Comment: What  chars do you consider "special"? Where is the regex used?

Comment: Any special character. I'm testing the first answer as it seems to work !

Comment: Is `ż` or `ź` special? Is space special?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well, I think it doesn't matter for those kind of characters.

Comment: @HabibKechrid So, what "kind of characters" matters?

Comment: Are you using this regex with a programming language such as Java or C#?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew non alphanumeric characters, like : ?!'")( etc... Non english characters do not realy matter for this case, they can be interpreted as alphanumeric.

Comment: So, `ł` or `ż` are considered alphanumeric and that means they are NOT special?

Comment: You could do it in two phases -- first filter out numbers, and check that what remains is four special characters; and then filter out everything except numbers, and check that you have one to six digits left.

Comment: I updated the question with more details.

Comment: Ok, so  this is JavaScript ECMAScript and the version depends on the browser. Sorry, but it is not easy to match any Unicode letter with that flavor. The best you can do is to consider only ASCII letters and digits as valid alphanumeric chars with a pattern like https://regex101.com/r/b7b41D/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This works fine for my case ! Thanks

Comment: Glad you finally made your mind about the requirements. I do not mind the downvotes on my answers, though I truly do not know why my correct, working, explained answer got downvoted. If you need more help with it let know via a comment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks again for the answer, I did accept and upvote it. Hope this helps other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
pattern="(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){1,6}[^0-9]*$)(?=(?:[A-Za-z0-9]*[^A-Za-z0-9]){4}[A-Za-z0-9]*$).*"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b7b41D/1)

Note that HTML5 regex is automatically wrapped with `^(?:` and `)$` so the resulting pattern will look like

```
/^(?:(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){1,6}[^0-9]*$)(?=(?:[A-Za-z0-9]*[^A-Za-z0-9]){4}[A-Za-z0-9]*$).*)$/
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){1,6}[^0-9]*$)` - 1 to 6 digits separated with any amount of non-digits allowed in the string
- `(?=(?:[A-Za-z0-9]*[^A-Za-z0-9]){4}[A-Za-z0-9]*$)` - exactly 4 chars other than ASCII letters or digits separated with any amount of ASCII letters or digits allowed in the string
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.